# Select Method of Range class failed While calling a Sub for the second time

Tags: vba, excel

Hi Please find my piece of code below. I call this subroutine each time when I need to populate a table name into my worksheet. All the variables which are not declared including workbook are declared as PUBLIC.

This sub is called many times during the entire run and for the first time it does what it is supposed to. But second time when the sub is called, it throws an error "Select Method of Range class failed". Not sure where it is going wrong.

Note: the wb is used in other sub as well. Is this a problem? Should I have to declare it locally on all my sub separately?

Kindly advice.

```
Sub TNPopulate(tablename As String)

    tablecount = tablecount + 1
    existingtable = tablename
    tablestart = row + 1

    wb.Sheets(2).Cells(tablestart, col) = existingtable
    wb.Sheets(2).Cells(tablestart, col).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that that sheet is not active. However you don't need to select anything here - you can manipulate the cell directly:

```
Sub TNPopulate(tablename As String)

    tablecount = tablecount + 1
    existingtable = tablename
    tablestart = Row + 1

    With wb.Sheets(2).Cells(tablestart, col)
        .Value = existingtable
        .Font.Bold = True
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```